# Open link on click after slideInUp animation

Tags: css, reactjs, animate.css

I am very new to react and animate.css. I am hoping the user can click on the panel and have a new link open, but for now it only works when the underlying image is clicked before the slideInUp animation (in this case it is the green panel with the text). Once the animation happens, it no longer works. The image is what it looks like after the animation.[the animation is the green background + text sliding down onto the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlLuV.png

```
export const Card = ({ title, description, imgUrl, link}) => { return (
    <Col size={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <div className="proj-imgbx">
      <a href={link} target="_blank">
        <img src={imgUrl} href={link}/>
      </a>

        <div className="proj-txtx">
          <h4>{title}</h4>
          <span>{description}</span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </Col>

  ) }
```